# Folds parameter in FURIA

Tags: machine-learning, classification, weka

I am presently working on a classification problem that I employ FURIA algorithm  from the WEKA package to solve. I am not sure of what does the "folds" parameter mean. The documentation states, that it " Determines the amount of data used for pruning. One fold is used for pruning, the rest for growing the rules.", I don't know how to interpret that, I have also noticed that with the increase of the "folds" parameter the number of generated rules tends to decrease. Does it mean that if I set fold to X training data will be divided between the growing and the pruning set in the respective ration of 19 to 1, or is it something else altogether?

Answer (score 0):

In the rule learning phase the data will be partitioned into training and testing data. The relation between training data and pruning data is (n-1) to 1 when n is the number of folds.

So, when the number of folds is too large in relation to number of instances and number of classes, it might happen that there is not enough testing data to properly evaluate the rule candidate performance and, thus, to select the "best" rules.